# NEXT JS - Problemas haciendo una build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs, next

Al hacer una build en Next JS 12 me devuelve este error

info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/12)/motos
/marca/[marcas]
/
/coches
/login
Error occurred prerendering page "/motos". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
at Object.only (C:\tmp\breeze-next\node_modules\react\cjs\react.production.min.js:19:357)
at LinkComponent (C:\tmp\breeze-next.next\server\chunks\664.js:637:39)

Si reviso el fichero de motos.js (aun por desarrollar) tengo este código

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import GuestLayout from '@/components/Layouts/GuestLayout'

export default function Home() {
   const [data, setData] = useState([])
   const cars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

return (
    <GuestLayout>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            MOTOS
        </div>
    </GuestLayout>
)
}
```

Comment: parece que el componente `Home` no es el del problema, parece que es `GuestLayout`. Basicamente el error es porque se estan pasando 2 elementos donde solo se espera 1

Comment: Muchas gracias @Isaac, si creo que el error viene por allí , como ves que guestlayout se le pasan 2 elementos cuando solo espera1? eso en la linea del error donde lo ves? gracias

Comment: El error esta casi en la mitad del texto que pusiste en la pregunta: _Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child. at Object.only_